# Inserting a Foreign Key into a table using C#

Tags: c#, sql

I hope you don't mind if I ask for your opinions about how to insert a foreign key into a table without running a couple of queries.

I have made a sample UI and a sample table just to illustrate my situation.

[image]

Here's what I usually do when inserting, first I do a query against the database and loads the result into the ComboBox. After that I run a query again to get the Id of the selectedItem on the comboBox before doing the INSERT or UPDATE query, but it feels like there is a much better solution without hitting the database too much.

Any idea will be greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Almost off-topic, but what is the reason to hold a table for gender? How many values do you expect there?

Comment: That just serve as a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When loading the items into the `ComboBox` you could use a dataset, say like retrieved from this

```
"SELECT Id, NameColumn FROM sampleTable"
```

Then you can set the `ComboBox` `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` attributes like so

```
combobox1.ValueMember = "Id";
combobox1.DisplayMember = "NameColumn";
```

That way, when you try to retrieve the `Id` of the item all you need to do is something like

```
var item = combobox1.SelectedValue;
```

You only need to hit the database now to load the items into the `ComboBox` in the first place, before your `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.